# I got a raise from 50,000 to 65,000, and paycheck calculator says that I should take home $867

Tags: united-states, taxes, new-york, raise

Hi I recently got a raise and wanted to calculate how much I would take home, and I get paid weekly.

If my salary is 65000, I live in NYC, and my weekly paycheck is $867, that is more than 30% of my gross pay going in to taxes. Is that right? I am filed as a single 2.

I feel like that is a lot of taxes to pay for the amount I am making.

Comment: Does the math on your paycheck add up? Your paystub should have an itemized list of money deducted from your check and what it is for.

Comment: Sounds about right.   See page 48 - $1250 weekly - $219 federal - http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf , figure $95 for FICA/SS and the remainder down to $867 is NY state tax.   Hmm, $69 dollars seems kinda low on the state side, maybe you'll need to disclose your # of deductions to get an accurate guess.

Comment: There's also New York city income tax as well, on top of the Federal and the State taxes.

Comment: I normally use a rule of thumb that ~33% of my salary will go to taxes, so that sounds right to me.

Answer (score 2):

On $65000, you are in the 25% marginal federal bracket. Once exemption and standard deduction are considered, the federal bill is about $9500. That's about 15% overall. Another 7.65% for social security/medicare, and you're at 22.65. 6.35% to cover NY city and state sounds right. Even a bit low.

I suggest you search for on line tax software, there are a number of them that can help you see if your withholding is good, or the effect of saving to a 401(k) or IRA.